# Why my XAMPP does not work?

Tags: xampp, connection

First, I'll tell you. My sister had inadvertently download an application containing the virus. Then I have deleted the application https://www.malwarebytes.com/. But, somehow. My XAMPP application does not work (maybe, erased when the virus quarantine). Like this

```
5:26:39 PM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
5:26:39 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
5:26:39 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
5:26:39 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
5:26:39 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
5:26:39 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
5:26:39 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

I've replaced potrt at **httpd.conf** and  **httpd-ssl.conf**. already replaced through setting and port settings, has been re-install xampp. But not work! 
In fact, I am also troubled mysql. Like this

[image]

```
5:28:37 PM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
5:28:37 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
5:28:37 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
5:28:37 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
5:28:37 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
5:28:37 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
5:28:37 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

***But it seems like there is no problem in my port***

[image]

And when I try to play online games, it also can not. I get a warning: Error in connection. This my **steam** and game **WOT**. but **NOT CONNECT**

[image]
[image]

But there was no problem at all, even I can browse through **google chrome** etc. Is it possible to fix without having to re-install my windows?

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall, whether it has blocked port or not.

Comment: Yess i check but No problem

Comment: Disable all your firewall + antivirus
--
Restart your system and then try.
Hope it works